# Eigenspaces and eigenvalues of $T(y)=t\frac{dy}{dt}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

We have the map $T(y)=t\frac{dy}{dt}$ defined on $\mathbb R[t]_n$, which is the set of real-valued polynomials up to degree $n$, and I must find its eigenvalues and eigenspaces. In this case, we have that $T(v)=\lambda v$, where $v=a_nt^n+a_{n-1}t^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0$. Then: $$nta_nt^{n-1}+(n-1)ta_{n-1}t^{n-2}+\cdots+ta_1=\lambda a_nt^n+\lambda a_{n-1}t^{n-1}+\cdots+\lambda a_0$$

From this, we have that: $$\lambda a_n=0 \\ \lambda a_{n-1}-nta_n=0 \\ \lambda a_{n-2}-(n-1)ta_{n-1}=0 \\ \vdots \\ \lambda a_0-ta_1=0$$ I know this this is supposed to assist me in finding an expression for the eigenvalues, but I do not know how to proceed from here. Also, how would I find the eigenspace, knowing that it is the set of all vectors satisfying $T(v)=\lambda v$? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your equalities don't seem to be correct. Using your first display equation and comparing like terms on both sides of $T(v) = \lambda v$ gives
\begin{align}
n a_n &= \lambda a_n\\
(n - 1) a_{n - 1} &= \lambda a_{n - 1}\\
&\,\,\,\!\vdots \\
a_1 &= \lambda a_1 \\
0 &= \lambda a_0.
\end{align}
If the first equality holds, then either $\lambda = n$ or $a_n = 0$. In the former case, the remaining equations force $a_{n - 1} = \cdots = a_0 = 0$, which hence defines a $1$d eigenspace of $T$, in particular spanned by $t^n$.

Now, what happens in the case $a_n = 0$?

Comment: If $a_n=0$, then $\lambda$ and $n$ can be arbitrary values, no? Then, can the eigenspace of $T$ be spanned by $1$?

Comment: Never mind; I have another attempt. If $a_n=0$, then we may have $\lambda \neq n$, but since we are working in $\mathbb R[t]_n$, we must have that $\lambda \leq n$. Then, the eigenspace is spanned by $t^n$, where $\lambda \leq n$. Is this correct?

Comment: The eigenspace for the particular eigenvalue $\lambda = n$ (not $\lambda \leq n$, any eigenspace by definition corresponds to a single eigenvalue) is spanned by $t^n$. If $a_n = 0$, then moving onto the second equation gives us that $\lambda = n - 1$ or $a_{n - 1} = 0$, but this is is just like our previous position, so...

Comment: Will it not inductively keep going until $\lambda=n-k$ or $a_{n-k}=0$? But what does this prove?

Comment: By definition, finding an eigenspace *is* finding a $\lambda$ for which there are nonzero solutions $v$ to $T v = \lambda v$ and then finding the space of such solutions. The answer describes one eigenspace, corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda = n$. We want to find the remaining eigenvalues and their respective spaces.

Comment: So, then each eigenspace is spanned by $t^{n-k}$ with $\lambda=n-k$ for $0\leq k \leq n$?

Comment: Yes, exactly, and our algebra shows that this exhausts all of the eigenvalues and eigenspaces. In fact, $\dim \mathbb{R}[t]_n = n + 1$, so we knew ahead of time that $T$ has exactly $n + 1$ eigenvalues, counting (algebraic) multiplicity.